# multiple array input and array output: SWIG C++ to python

Tags: python, c++, arrays, swig, inout

I am trying to access a C++ function from python by using SWIG for wrapping. The function uses two arrays as inputs of length `cL` and another as output of some smaller length. The SWIG .i file is :

```
%module polcvx
%include "typemaps.i"
%apply int *INPUT {int *cL};
%typemap(in) float r[cL] (float temp[cL]) {
  int i;
  if (!PySequence_Check($input)) {
PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expected a sequence");
SWIG_fail;
  }
  if (PySequence_Length($input) != cL) {
   PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Size mismatch. Expected more or less elements than 4th argument");
   SWIG_fail;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < cL; i++) {
   PyObject *o = PySequence_GetItem($input, i);
  }
  $1 = temp;
  }
%typemap(in) float t[cL] (float temp1[cL]) {
  int i;
  if (!PySequence_Check($input)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expected a sequence");
    SWIG_fail;
  }
  if (PySequence_Length($input) != cL) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Size mismatch. Expected more or less elements than 4th argument");
    SWIG_fail;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < cL; i++) {
    PyObject *o = PySequence_GetItem($input, i);
  }
  $2  = temp1;
 }
  %typemap(in, numinputs=0) int *hull[ANY] (int temp2[ANY]) {
  $3 = &temp2;
 }
 %typemap(argout) int *hull[ANY] {
  int i;
   $result = PyList_New($3_dim0);
  for (i = 0; i < $3_dim0; i++) {
    PyObject *o = PyFloat_FromDouble((double) $3[i]);
    PyList_SetItem($result, i, o);
   }
}
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "cvxp.hpp"
 %}
 int cvx( int hull[],float r[], float t[], int cL);
```

and implemented in python as

```
import _polcvx
rad=[10,5,2,20,15,7,10,45,12]
theta=[0.5236   , 0.7854 ,   1.5708  ,  2.6180 ,   2.9671   , 3.3161  ,  4.0143   , 4.7124  ,  6.1087]
l=len(rad)
ls=[]
i=_polcvx.cvx(5,rad2,theta,l)
```

I am getting an error in python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Hull\cpp and py conversion\CvxPolar.py", line 65, in <module>
    i=_polcvx.cvx(ls,rad2,theta,l)
TypeError: in method 'cvx', argument 1 of type 'int []'
```

Since the function uses pointer to access array variable, cant figure out the correct configuration to be done in .i file.

Comment: So `cL` specifies the length of 3 arrays?

Comment: no, 2 arrays have length of cL, the length of 3rd array is returned by the function.

Comment: How should we know how big to allocate the array for the output argument then? This would be much simpler to understand the semantics of your function if you showed a representative but working placeholder for it and not just the declaration.

Comment: `int cvx( int hull[],float r[], float t[], int cL);`, `i=_polcvx.cvx(5,rad2,theta,l)`: formal and actual arguments seem to differ. Maybe: `i = _polcvx.cvx(ls, rad, theta, l)`?

Comment: Try to include `%array_class(float, float ArrayClass)` and similarly for `int`. Then from within python you can create arrays and pass them as arguments instead of python lists.